# Listing css and javascript path from flask application

Tags: javascript, css, flask

I have a flask project with a directory structure like so:

```
--flaskwebsite
----routes.py
----routes.pyc
----templates
------index.html
-----static
-------(several CSS and javascript folders and files)
```

Whenever I render my index.html page it loads correctly but without all the CSS and javascript, and I'm unaware of why.

Here is an example of how I list a path:

```
vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

(the vendor folder is inside the static folder as of now)

so far I have just had the path for the CSS and javascript directly. But how can I add it so, that it moves out the directory and into my static folder to access all the CSS and javascript?

Is my directory listing correct, or should I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add: 
    ../static/
in front of every folder, you a listing, so that you will go up a directory, and then into the static folder.